# unexported classes in a C++ shared library

Tags: c++, qt

I am a bit confused about creating a shared library in Qt, actualy in C++, there is no Qt specific question in my problem. Here is a scenario.

This is the global header for my shared library.

```
#if defined(MYAPI_LIBRARY)
#  define MYAPI Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYAPI Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

and this is an exported class.

```
#include "myapi_global.h"
#include "MyClass2.h"
#include "MyClass3.h"
#include "myfuncs.h"

class MYAPI MyClass1
{
...
public:
    MyClass2 myClass2;
private:
    MyClass3 myClass3;
};
```

and this is an unexported class used by MyClass1

```
class MyClass3
{
..
}
```

and this is an other unexported class used by MyClass1

```
class MyClass2
{
..
}
```

one last header file for a non-classed functions (myfuncs.h).

```
int foo() {...}
```

My questions are:

1. Are my MyClass2, MyClass3 and foo() visible for the user of the shared library? Can user use them? If yes, then MYAPI keyword seem meaningless.
2. Is there any mistake for the pattern for creating a shared library in C++?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using MSVC with OpenGL x32/x64 but I'm going to use Android Kits for Qt in Win8x64 platform. Is that relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a symbol is exported or not by default depends on the compiler.
In MSVC, no symbols are exported by default. Under MSVC, only MyClass1 should be visible by external users of the DLL. In GCC, all symbols are exported by default.

Your code, as far as I can see, looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just wanted to parse my application under development to some parts; 1.Core Lib, 2.Second Lib uses Core Lib and 3. GUI uses all. Or sth like that.

Comment: @Cahit: That sounds like a reasonable split!

Comment: Btw. Can't user acces myClass2 variable on MyClass1? It is a public member.

Comment: @Cahit: Ah, well, that's a problem. If it's public, it's still not automatically exported (under MSVC). If a client uses it, they'll get a link error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those classes are not part of anonymous namespace, since `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` do not have explicit visibility attributes, it defaults to default symbol visibility.

From this point the behavior depends on the compiler. The default visibility is "public" in both Clang and GCC unless changed with `-fvisibility` option (or pragma), so those two classes would be exported from the DSO.

The best way to avoid having unintended symbols exported, I recommend you change visibility to hidden by default (`fvisibility=hidden`) and export only symbols you need.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Is public and private classes in C# modifying fvisibility options in background or sth like that?

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü C#? I have no idea.

Comment: @Cahit: C# (.NET) is a whole other story. The types are included in the assebmly either way, but the assembly's metadata is different; the compiler won't let you access private things (or internal things from another assembly). But you can bypass this through reflection at run-time.